# Given point and function find the vector

Tags: calculus

A small ball is released from $(-1,2,11)$ on $z=x^3-3xy^2$. Which vector does it start moving on?
I found the normal $(-9,12,-1)$ and I know its not the answer. I really don't have any idea other then that. There no additional information given.

Comment: I suppose is the grandient direction (minus actually). The equation $z=x^3 -3xy^2$ represente a surface so the gradient vector represent the direction of maximun growth, so minus the gradiente indicate the directiont of minimum growth.